# Mirror Linux disk writes to secondary disk

Tags: linux, raid, storage, software-raid

I would like to set up a Linux system to use one primary storage device, but copy all writes to that device to another secondary device without blocking for every write - e.g. an NVMe SSD as primary and spinning rust as secondary.

The only way I can think of doing this currently would be to either run a frequent `rsync` in the background, or something like a `btrfs-send` of the live stream of disk writes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a MD RAID1 with the option `--write-mostly`.

> subsequent devices listed in a --build, --create, or --add command will be flagged as 'write-mostly'.  This is valid for RAID1 only and means that the 'md' driver will avoid reading from these devices if at all possible.  This can be useful if mirroring over a slow link.

I use this when I want a fast SSD but have the data on a second, spinning drive.

Comment: Thanks, with that I did some more research and found the ability to use both `--write-mostly` and `--write-behind`. I'll mark my question as a duplicate of that answer.